# Fill remaining height with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have a navbar at the top of a page, in a fluid container, now I want to fill the remaining space below (responsively) with another fluid container that wraps an SVG element. I can size the bottom container with `container-fluid full` and I can insert two rows `row half`, or one row with `row half`, but ideally, I want to be able to put a single row with `row full` but this doesn't work.

My plan is to use the height of the row to define my svg element height.

How can I do this so I maximise the svg size without scroll bars appearing?